# Converting output to a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below data from JIRA. I am trying to have this converted into a pandas Dataframe.

```
[<JIRA Sprint: name='Sprint_1', id=101>,
 <JIRA Sprint: name='Sprint_2', id=102>]
```

Expected output:

```
col_1, col_2
Sprint_1, 101
Sprint_2, 102
```

When I try doing `pd.Dataframe()`, it only returns back the `name` and does not return back `id`

Comment: Is your sample input a list?

Comment: @PacketLoss, it's of type `jira.client.ResultList`

Comment: Can you provide your current output where it only returns the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [source code](https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/blob/7fa3a454c08a14e2d7d7670fcfa87482e16936ba/jira/client.py#L131) `ResultList` class is inherited from the builtin list object, and also you can access the `id` and `name` using `spring_obj.attribute` syntax because `Sprint` class implements [`__getattr__`](https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/blob/7fa3a454c08a14e2d7d7670fcfa87482e16936ba/jira/resources.py#L173) method.

```
import pandas as pd

result = [
    <JIRA Sprint: name='Sprint_1', id=101>,
    <JIRA Sprint: name='Sprint_2', id=102>,
]

rows = {"col_1": [], "col_2": []}

for sprint in result:
    rows["col_1"].append(sprint.name)
    rows["col_2"].append(sprint.id)

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```